# unable to add bootstrap tooltip on <select> tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, jquery-tooltip

i want to add a bootom-tooltip on my select box but unable to do so.its showing nothing on hover.

Here is my code for select box:

```
<select class="navbar-search pull-left span1" name="currency" id="select-currency" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Here is my tooltip jquery:

```
<script>
     jQuery(function(){
        $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
    });
​</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("[data-toggle=tooltip]")` (with an additional ])?

Comment: @dystroy: yes u are right i have edited my question.

Comment: your code is correct check you bootstrap js and jquery file are place in correct folder

Comment: @rajeshkakawat: i have included all the files onlien as suggested by shina but somehow its not working.

Comment: @Monty did you check console any error is coming or not ?????????

Comment: @rajeshkakawat: its working now but i think the problem is in php code coz its working fine with static option values but not workingwith dynamic values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me, take a look at this: [bootstrap tooltip on  tag](http://jsbin.com/kirut/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @Monty ... does the demo work for you? if so then check your script thoroughly. As you can see, I added your select options without the PHP. So it should work.

Comment: @Monty ... really strange, are you loading the jQuery and Bootstrap properly?

Comment: @Shina: i have used ur whole code sir and somehow its not working..:(

Comment: @Monty ... as rajesh kakawat pointed, everything seems correct and you can see from the demo. Check your meta tags script.

Comment: @Shina: its working now i think the problem is dynamic option values i just add ur static values and its working now

Comment: Good, so try to fix the dynamic options and you should be fine. Please remember to accept my answer so it's useful for others.